# Errors during database deployment

Tags: sql-server, deployment

Our database has many schemas with identical structure, during deployment of database we generate updating script for one schema with help of dacpack and then this script is used for updating all schemas in parallel. 
And during deployment there are errors executing ALTER PROCEDURE for one procedure in several schemas (so deployment process fails), but when execute this ALTER PROCEDURE script in SSMS it completes succesfully for all schemas, and executing this procedure works without errors. 
So why errors executing ALTER PROCEDURE can happen during deployment, and what we can do to overcome this?

Comment: If you provided some information about what errors the ALTER PROCEDURE was giving then there is a small chance people could help further. As it is, this question is likely to be closed with "unclear what you're asking" or "not enough information" comments.

Comment: It sounds like your maybe missing a GO statement somewhere in your deployment script.